# What is a CarmenFeature used by the Mapbox Android SDK?

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm trying to understand some sample code from Mapbox that uses CarmenFeature, but I don't understand what it is or what it's for.

The method I'm referring to is shown below for context, although I'm not looking for an explanation for the method itself.

Thanks!

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {

        // Retrieve selected location's CarmenFeature
        CarmenFeature selectedCarmenFeature = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(data);

        // Create a new FeatureCollection and add a new Feature to it using selectedCarmenFeature above.
        // Then retrieve and update the source designated for showing a selected location's symbol layer icon

        if (mapboxMap != null) {
            Style style = mapboxMap.getStyle();
            if (style != null) {
                GeoJsonSource source = style.getSourceAs(geojsonSourceLayerId);
                if (source != null) {
                    source.setGeoJson(FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(
                            new Feature[] {Feature.fromJson(selectedCarmenFeature.toJson())}));
                }

                // Move map camera to the selected location
                mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                        new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(new LatLng(((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).latitude(),
                                        ((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).longitude()))
                                .zoom(14)
                                .build()), 4000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CarmenFeature` is the name of the class that holds the information from [a Mapbox Geocoding API response](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#geocoding-response-object).

[Here's the `CarmenFeature` class, which comes from the Mapbox Java SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/services-geocoding/src/main/java/com/mapbox/api/geocoding/v5/models/CarmenFeature.java).

You'll see `CarmenFeature` mentioned several times in [the Java SDK's `GeocodingResponse` class](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/services-geocoding/src/main/java/com/mapbox/api/geocoding/v5/models/GeocodingResponse.java).

Comment: I will look more into this, thank you for the resources!